# How to remove duplicate on a jsonb column with nested list

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to remove the duplicates of a data with from a jsonb column

my table has 3 column 1 is for id which is auto generated 1 is for source_id and column 3 is for the jsonb data

data:

```
id | source_id | column_3
---+-----------+-------------------------------------------
1  | 1         | [
   |           |   [
   |           |     {"header": "name","value": "mike"},
   |           |     {"header": "age","value": "23"}
   |           |   ], [
   |           |     {"header": "name","value": "may"},
   |           |     {"header": "age","value": "19"}
   |           |   ]
   |           | ]
---+-----------+-------------------------------------------
2  | 1         | [
   |           |   [
   |           |     {"header": "name","value": "mike"},
   |           |     {"header": "age","value": "23"}
   |           |   ], [
   |           |     {"header": "name","value": "jay"},
   |           |     {"header": "age","value": "19"}
   |           |   ]
   |           | ]
---+-----------+-------------------------------------------
3  | 2         | [
   |           |   [
   |           |     {"header": "name","value": "mike"},
   |           |     {"header": "age","value": "23"}
   |           |   ], [
   |           |     {"header": "name","value": "ben"},
   |           |     {"header": "age","value": "26"}
   |           |   ]
   |           | ]
```

Need to remove duplicate data on same source_id

expected result:

```
id  | source_id | column_3
----+-----------+-------------------------------------------
1   | 1         | [
    |           |   [
    |           |     {"header": "name","value": "mike"},
    |           |     {"header": "age","value": "23"}
    |           |   ], [
    |           |     {"header": "name","value": "may"},
    |           |     {"header": "age","value": "19"}
    |           |   ]
    |           | ]
----+-----------+-------------------------------------------
2   | 1         | [
    |           |   [
    |           |     {"header": "name","value": "jay"},
    |           |     {"header": "age","value": "19"}
    |           |   ]
    |           | ]
----+-----------+-------------------------------------------
3   | 2         | [
    |           |   [
    |           |     {"header": "name","value": "mike"},
    |           |     {"header": "age","value": "23"}
    |           |   ], [
    |           |     {"header": "name","value": "ben"},
    |           |     {"header": "age","value": "26"}
    |           |   ]
    |           | ]
```

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you mean by 'duplicate data'. What is the duplicate in the input? Why? Why does the ouput not contain any duplicate?

Comment: the duplicate is
 {"header": "name","value": "mike"},
 {"header": "age","value": "23"}
on row1 source id 1
it has duplicate on row2 source id 1 then the duplicates must be removed must be like the expected result

Comment: But why? Are you looking for nested objects inside the JSON arrays? How exactly? What would *not* be a duplicate?

Comment: If you have to remove duplicates from a JSON value, it's strong indication that you shouldn't have used JSON to begin with. With a properly normalized model you could ensure this through a unique constraint.

Comment: I am correcting false data insert. thats why i am trying to remove the duplicate it means one data is 1 List<HeaderValue> and column 3 consist of List<List<HeaderValue>>. You can see that on source_id=1 they both have {"header": "name","value": "mike"}, {"header": "age","value": "23"} so one must be removed

Comment: @Mike If the order matters then you will need to create a stored function. Just because the `update` statement is not ordered.

Comment: @Abelisto if you have some sample because im just new here on postgres